# How to save an xml attachment using element name as file name in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, outlook

I currently have two modules which work as required in VBA created from bits and pieces I found using Google.

I would like to combine them into one process that Outlook can handle as a rule.

The first module saves an XML email attachment with a date extension from outlook and is activated by outlook rules.

The second uses `getElementsByTagName` to display the serial number from a file located on my hard drive in a msgbox.

Is there a way to combine these two into one automated process which saves the XML attachment from the email and renames it with the serial number element tag name from the xml attachment?

The code for each is listed below.

Module 1:

```
Public Sub saveXMLtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim dateFormat
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\temp\xml folder\"
dateFormat = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy H-mm-ss")

 For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xml") Then
     objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName & dateFormat & ".xml"

      End If
      Set objAtt = Nothing
      Pause 1
      Next
End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Sub GetSN()

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Temp\savetest.xml")

Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SerialNumber")
For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
MsgBox nodeXML(i).Text

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially have everything that you need already, and could actually literally combine your code into a single routine with some minor changes.

In your `GetSN` routine, you are currently displaying the Serial Number in a Message Box `MsgBox nodeXML(i).Text`.

Instead of doing this, you should assign it to a variable to easily refer to it later eg.

`serialNumber = nodeXML(i).Text`

Now in 'saveXMLtoDisk' simply include this when you save the file.

`objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName & " " & serialNumber & " " & dateFormat & ".xml"`

In the simplest terms, place the contents of `GetSN` at the top of your existing `saveXMLtoDisk` routine and make the above changes.

*Edited in response to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532319/how-to-save-an-xml-attachment-using-element-name-as-file-name-in-vba/34532983#comment56812888_34532983) about extracting the Serial Number from the attached XML file.*

I think the easiest way to do this would be to save a temporary copy of the attached XML file somewhere on the PC, and then refer to that when you call `xmlDoc.Load`. Once you've captured the Serial Number you can then delete this temporary copy and save the permanent copy with the properly formatted name. I've copied a full code example below (comments in-line with the code where I've changed your original code).

```
Public Sub saveXMLtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim dateFormat As String
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\temp\xml folder\" 
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy H-mm-ss")

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xml") Then

            ' Save the XML to a temporary location
            Dim tempXML As String: tempXML = "C:\temp\attachment.xml"
            Dim serialNumber As String

            ' Start of GetSN Code
            Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
            xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
            xmlDoc.async = False
            ' Open the temporary copy of the XML attachment that has been saved.
            xmlDoc.Load (tempXML)

            Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SerialNumber")
            For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
                serialNumber = nodeXML(i).Text
            Next

            Set nodeXML = Nothing
            Set xmlDoc = Nothing
            ' End of GetSN Code

            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName & " " & serialNumber & " " & dateFormat & ".xml"

            ' Remove the temporary copy of the XML attachment
            Kill tempXML

        End If

        Set objAtt = Nothing
        Pause 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
So,  would I leave out the xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Temp\savetest.xml") reference if I wanted it to it so scan the current xml attachment and not just the one located in the temp folder?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you said you wanted to get the Serial Number out of the attached XML file. I think the easiest way to do this would be to save a temporary copy of attachment somewhere, and then refer to this copy in your `xmlDoc.Load`. Once that is done you would delete this copy, and save the actual file with the properly formatted name. I've edited the answer with an example for doing this.

Comment: That worked!  I only had to add a few references and all is well.  I added: tempfolder = "c:\temp\" at the top, and: objAtt.SaveAsFile tempfolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName under save xml to temp location.